# Presence of text in multiple elements selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to check the presence of text prior to its retrieval in a list of elements using selenium in Python on the following [link](https://www.ahs.dep.pa.gov/eFACTSWeb/searchResults_singleFacility.aspx?FacilityID=4468).

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.ahs.dep.pa.gov/eFACTSWeb/searchResults_singleFacility.aspx?FacilityID=276740')

table_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td')))
permit_table = [i for i in table_list if i.text == 'Facility Search Permit Details'][0]
```

I attempt to store in the `permit_table` variable a table for which the `.text` attribute contains the string "Facility Search Permit Details".
While the `table_list` variable correctly retrieves the elements I am interested about (a list of all tables corresponding to the XPATH I entered), when I want to access the elements' respective `.text` attributes through list comprehension , `permit_table` returns an empty list.

Is there a way to introduce an implicit wait for the visibility of the text attribute of the `WebElement` corresponding to each item of the list `table_list`? I am aware of the `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element` method but it only works when looking for a single element, which is not my case as `table_list` returns a list of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. If you were actually running your posted code, it would have thrown on this line

   ```
   table_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ...))).get_attribute("text")
   ```

   with this error

   ```
   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
   ```

   `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located()` returns a list. `.get_attribute()` must be used on a single element, not a list.
2. Even if the above line was corrected, `table_list` would be a collection of strings, not elements so `if i.text` would not work. In your list comprehension, you are assuming `i` is an element but it's a string.

Having said all that, I'm assuming you are trying to get the TABLE that is labelled "Facility Search Permit Details" and loop through the rows, scraping the data, etc. The easier way to do this is

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.ahs.dep.pa.gov/eFACTSWeb/searchResults_singleFacility.aspx?FacilityID=276740')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
permit_details_table_rows = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[.//td[text()='Facility Search Permit Details']]/following-sibling::div[1]/table//tr")))
print(len(permit_details_table_rows))
```

This prints `6`.

This will give you `permit_details_table_rows` which contains all rows of that TABLE that you can loop through, etc.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to remove the ```.get_attribute("text")```. I have modified my post.  If you run it without that part, ```i``` is not a string but a single element.

Comment: your solution to get collect the tables' texts within a single XPATH does seem more efficient than my approach, thanks you!